# vuex2.0 component methods option :mix mapActions with local defined methods not work

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When i use vuejs2.0 and vuex2.0 to structure my app, in the component defination, i'd like import some methods defined by actions and also i'd like to declare some other local functions in this way:

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    methods:{
      doJob: function(){
          changeme(content)
      },
      mapActions([
          'changeme'
      ])
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, compiler always complain :

```
SyntaxError:
```

Comment: You might also want to look at Vue mixins https://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer:

```
methods:{
  doJob: function(){
    changeme(content)
  },
  ...mapActions([
    'changeme'
  ])
```

Comment: sorry this answer is actually working, but I down vote it by mistake. Can you please edit it so that I can re-vote?